# MySQL ST_AsGeoJSON is returning floating point figures not in original data

Tags: php, mysql, geojson

I am using PHP to save a row in a database. One field is of the type `geometry`. I save a `POINT` with the coordinates `52.5219` and `13.4132`.

When I retrieve the row, I use `ST_AsGeoJSON`. It returns me:

```
"geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [
        52.5219000000000022509993868879973888397216796875,                        
        13.413199999999999789679350215010344982147216796875
    ]
}
```

I want the results without the extra digits. This is only happening on my staging server. On my local server it returns the correct coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem.
you can read more about this from here: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=41357

How it produces?
When you subtract an integer number from a float number sometimes it will gives you this type of error.
For example:

> var_dump(214.16569 - 214);
>
> var_dump(114.16569 - 114);

Solution:

There are several way to fix this issue.
I use the below code to limit the digit after the decimal. To limit upto 4 digit:

> $value = number_format($value, 4);

you can use the above code to format your data. It will show only 4 digit after the decimal.

Comment: But this is the number being returned by MySQL. It seems to be an MySQL problem rather than a PHP problem.